# Return Resultset from SQL Server to VB.NET application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, resultset, cursors

I need to return a resultset consisting of database errors from a SQL Server stored procedure's `CATCH` clause but I'm stuck with it. Do I need to use cursors to return resultset and if so, then what is the type declaration for the `OUTPUT` parameter in my .NET application? I tried `Object` and `Variant` but did not work.

I also tried the simple way just using a `SELECT` statement to return and it works with one stored procedure but not with another as thus in my `CATCH` clause:

```
 while (@I <= @count)
 begin      
    BEGIN TRY       
        -- delete all previous rows inserted in @customerRow for previous counts @I     
        delete from @customerRow

        -- this is inserting the current row that we want to save in database
        insert into @customerRow 
           SELECT  
               [id],[firstname], [lastname], [street], [city],
               [phone],[mobile],[fax], [email], [companyName],
               [licence],[brn], [vat], [companyStreet], [companyCity], [status]
           FROM 
               (SELECT  
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownumber,
                   [id], [firstname], [lastname], [street], [city],
                   [phone], [mobile], [fax], [email], [companyName],
                   [licence], [brn], [vat], [companyStreet], [companyCity], [status]
                FROM    
                   @registerDetails) AS foo
          WHERE 
             rownumber = @I                                             

       -- this stored procedure handles the saving of the current customer row just defined above
        -- if there is any error from that sproc, it will jump to CATCH block 
        --save the error message in the temp table and continue 
        --with the next customer row in the while loop.
        exec dbo.sp_SaveCustomer @customerRow
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TranCount = 0
        -- Transaction started in procedure.
        -- Roll back complete transaction.
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        if XACT_STATE()= -1 rollback transaction

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;


        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' ' + (select firstname from @registerDetails where id=@I)
        SELECT @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        SELECT @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE() 

        INSERT INTO #registrationResults (error,id)
        SELECT @ErrorMessage, @I 

    END CATCH       

    set @I = @I +1              
end 
COMMIT TRANSACTION registerTran

select * from #registrationResults
```

The above works with one stored procedure when I call it in my vb.net code as :

```
ta.Fill(registrationErrors, clientDetailsDT)
```

where `registrationErrors` and `clientDetailsDT` are strongly typed data tables.

This one does not :

```
    begin catch
    IF @@TranCount > 0 or XACT_STATE()= -1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorLine INT;


    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    SELECT @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    SELECT @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
    SELECT @ErrorLine = ERROR_Line();

    ****ERROR -- THIS SELECT WAS MESSING ALL UP as it was this select that was being        returned to the .NET and not the select of the desired #temp table after, hence returning 0    resultset as this select was EMPTY. !!  
    select status_indicator from InsertInvoiceTriggerData where session_GUID =   guid**
    delete from InsertInvoiceTriggerData where session_GUID = @guid**

    INSERT INTO #registrationResults (error,id)
    SELECT @ErrorMessage, NULL

    select * from #registrationResults

end catch
```

Any suggestions how to return resultsets?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your database code, but in my experience the very first error caught by `catch` means that the entire transaction has to be rolled back. Apart from other things, it also implies that I never have more than 1 error to return in any given situation.

As such, I use 2 scalar output parameters in my stored procedures, that is:

```
@Error int = null output,
@Message nvarchar(2048) = null output
```

And I can retrieve them just like any other output variables.

**UPD:** Even after you have added some code, I still fail to understand what is your problem, exactly. However, I see several problems with your code, so I'll point them out and chances are, one of them will solve the problem. I am commenting only the first snippet, since the last one is too incomplete.

- You should have been started the outermost transaction somewhere before the loop. If not, the code will fail.
- If I guessed correctly, you implemented all savepoint logic inside the `dbo.sp_SaveCustomer` stored proc. If not, the whole discussion is pointless, since there are no `save tran` or `rollback @savepoint` statements in the code you have shown.
- The first `catch` statement - `IF @@TranCount = 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` is all wrong. If the condition is successful, it will result in error trying to rollback nonexistent transaction. Should not be here if you rely on savepoints.
- The next after it should result in unconditional break: 
  `if XACT_STATE()= -1 begin
  rollback transaction;
  break;
  end;`
- The rest of your catch code can be replaced with this: 
  `INSERT INTO @registrationResults (error, id)
  SELECT error_message() + ' ' + firstname, id
  from @registerDetails where id=@I;`
- Also, never use temp tables for this purpose, because rollback will affect them as well. Always use table variables for this, they are non-transactional (just like any other variable).
- The `commit` should be conditional, because you may end up at this point with no transaction to commit:
  `if @@trancount > 0 commit tran;`
- There is no point in specifying savepoint name in the `commit` statement, it only leads to confusion (though isn't considered an error). Also, there should not any savepoint in this module (unless you have defined it before the loop).

I suspect that's just the tip of the iceberg, since I have no idea what actually happens inside the `dbo.SaveCustomer` stored procedure.

**UPD2:** Here is a sample of my VB.NET code which I use to receive recordsets from stored procedures:

```
Private Function SearchObjectsBase( _
    SearchMode As penum_SEARCH_MODE, SearchCriteria As String
) As DataSet

Dim Cmd As DbCommand, Pr As DbParameter, dda As DbDataAdapter

' Initialise returning dataset object
SearchObjectsBase = New DataSet()

Cmd = MyBase.CreateCommand(String.Format("dbo.{0}", SearchMode))

With Cmd

    ' Parameter definitions
    Pr = .CreateParameter()
    With Pr
        .ParameterName = "@SearchCriteria"
        .DbType = DbType.Xml
        .Value = SearchCriteria
    End With
    .Parameters.Add(Pr)

    ' Create data adapter to use its Fill() method
    dda = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(.Connection).CreateDataAdapter()
    ' Assign the prepared DbCommand as a select method for the adapter
    dda.SelectCommand = Cmd

    ' A single resultset is expected here
    dda.Fill(SearchObjectsBase)

End With

' Set error vars and get rid of it
Call MyBase.SetErrorOutput(Cmd)

' Check for errors and, if any, discard the dataset
If MyBase.ErrorNumber <> 0 Then SearchObjectsBase.Clear()

End Function
```

I use .NET 4.5, which has a very nice method to automatically select the most appropriate data adapter based on the actual connection.
And here is a call of this function:

```
Dim XDoc As New XElement("Criteria"), DS As DataSet = Nothing, DT As DataTable
...
DS = .SearchPatients(XDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.None))
' Assign datasource to a grid
Me.dgr_Search.DataSource = DS.Tables.Item(0)
```

Here, SearchPatients() is a wrapper on top of the SearchObjectsBase().

Comment: Scalar parameters work fine with single output as you mentioned but in my case, I have a transaction going on in a while loop, and each time the transaction does not succeed, it rolls back to a saved point and saving the error message in a temp table as above.  When the loop has completed, it returns the resultset fine.  But say you wanted to return the parameters you mentioned in a temp table from the CATCH block, how would you achieve it?

Comment: Well, you can transform your error resultset into XML and return it via an XML output parameter. Because, even as of 2014, the table variable parameters are still read-only.

Comment: Please have a look at the original post again, I have included the database code.  Also, according to MSDN documentation this works between stored procedures but how do we read cursors from say .NET? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand your problem. You have the right code and the wrong code; why try to use the wrong one? It will spawn a separate recordset for every error encountered with a single row in each. Why you cannot use the correct one?

Comment: And, just for the record, the data type for a parameter that returns cursor is called, strangely enough, `cursor`. But I don't have a slightest idea how to handle it on the client side, assuming it's ever possible.

Comment: Just to summarize the code and where the problem is.  The code that works uses a SELECT * from temporary table not in the CATCH block and this works while the one that uses the same SELECT * from temporary table inside the CATCH does not return anything!  Strange.   The Wrong one is used in another Stored procedure from the Right one btw so am wondering why the same code does not work in those two different situation.  Will have a look at the XML you suggested in the meantime as I've never used it from a .NET application.

Comment: @user2043688, the select from inside the loop can be suppressed at some level, by drivers or whatever. Have you tried to run the procedure from Management Studio and look at the results? Anyway, it's a completely wrong approach, I don't understand why you are so stuck to it.

Comment: Yes I did run the sproc in Management Studio and worked fine.  Every error in the customerRow gets saved in the temp table until loop is over and I return all the errors to the caller.  That's the directive I followed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx which corresponds to the dbo.sp_SaveCustomer sproc called above in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections above Roger.  The outer transaction RegisterTran does indeed start before the loop.  Will delete the commit transaction statements in this sproc as it was done exactly as in the above MSDN article in sp_SaveCustomer.  Also, there is an issue about returning temp tables to .NET as I've found out here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic969503-338-1.aspx.  Did replace temp table with table variable but to no avail again, still returning 0 as resultset.

Comment: @user2043688, oh, so that's what the problem is. Haven't encountered this before, probably because I try to avoid temp tables at all costs. Strange, I have several procs that return datasets (at least) partially based on table variables, and everything works perfectly. I'll update my answer with the sample of my VB.NET code.

Comment: Roger you wont believe it man, finally found out the crap that was causing the error!  CANT BELIEVE IT!  Modified the SECOND example where it was not working to show the error that I did not include in the post thinking it was not necessary !!!!  Complete nightmare... Thanks for the corrections though mate.

Comment: @user2043688 Well, mate, that was rather bold reduction :) Of course this resultset went in the way... good that you found it.